# huge delay between request in Tomcat 8.0.53 and spring boot tuning maxConnections / maxThreads / acceptCount

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm trying to understand how maxConnections / maxThreads / acceptCount works to fine tune my container.
According to [tomcat-8.0-doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#Introduction) and [spring-boot 1.5.8.RELEASE docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle) I create [this](https://github.com/stefanoriffaldi/poc-tomcat-max-connections-2) sample project.

I encounter a strange behavior:
If I set maxConnection = maxThreads = 1 and acceptCount = 1 ( just because 0 means infinite ) and I send 5 concurrent request, I expect 3 "Connection refused", and other 2 perform "sleep", one after the other ( because of maxThreads = 1 ).

So, the sequence is correct, but there is somwthing wrong:

Client side: all as expected

```
15:33:49.455 INFO  ConnectionTest:52 [2] Getting Response Code
15:33:49.455 INFO  ConnectionTest:52 [4] Getting Response Code
15:33:49.456 INFO  ConnectionTest:52 [0] Getting Response Code
15:33:49.455 INFO  ConnectionTest:52 [3] Getting Response Code
15:33:49.461 INFO  ConnectionTest:52 [1] Getting Response Code
15:33:51.499 ERROR ConnectionTest:56 [0] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:33:51.499 ERROR ConnectionTest:56 [2] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:33:51.499 ERROR ConnectionTest:56 [3] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
15:33:59.483 INFO  ConnectionTest:54 [1] Response Code: 200
15:35:10.041 INFO  ConnectionTest:54 [4] Response Code: 200
```

Server side: there is a huge delay between the end of the first request and start of the second

```
15:33:49.473 INFO  SampleController:33 [D81EE650351DA872CBD15589A91BE129] sleep 10
15:33:59.479 INFO  SampleController:36 [D81EE650351DA872CBD15589A91BE129] ending [10006ms]
15:35:00.034 INFO  SampleController:33 [2B8A8D158EF02D1A054F067FC0A8273F] sleep 10
15:35:10.038 INFO  SampleController:36 [2B8A8D158EF02D1A054F067FC0A8273F] ending [10004ms]
```

I tried to perform client task via Java Code (in test folder) and via SOAP UI / PostMan / curl and the delay found is different, so I thinks is something in client side.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Client also shows 2 minutes or so delay. My bet is that client is not closing the connection so the server closes it after the timeout expired and then it serves the queued request.

Comment: `HttpURLConnection.getInputSteam().close()`

Comment: @LMC that's it, thanks so much ! how I can do that when i launch curl ?

Comment: What do you mean curl? On command line? Besides, I added the answer that you can accept and upvote if you wish.

Comment: @LMC yes I mean via command line. Issue is that, code confirm, what Im asking for is why its happening via CURL ? how can I close connection when I launch "curl -v http://localhost:8080/sleep" ?

Comment: Try sending the header `curl -v -H "Connection: close" example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client also shows a delay of 2 minutes or so. That client is not closing the connection so the server closes it after the timeout expired and then it serves the queued request.

To close the conection on client side add

```
HttpURLConnection.getInputSteam().close()
```